# Fetch current location of a Google Plus user's contact

Tags: google-people-api

I would like to access the location of a User's contact.

Given, that the user is authenticated and the requested contact has granted access to his location data (Location Sharing).

This is basically the same thing as in the Google+ Android App under "Locations" or in the web app, when you open the "About me" information.

I searched the People API, but apparently the "getCurrentLocation" method does not seem to provide that information anymore (delivers NULL).

Thank you for your hints and tips